# how to reference kivy widget ids dynamically created using kv language through a for loop in main python file?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have dynamically created textinput widgets in a .kv file using kv language. However i would like to set the text in main python file using a for loop by referencing their ids.
I have written the following code:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class setText(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        texts=['txtip1','txtip2']
        IDS=self.ids.keys()
        for i in range(IDS):
            self.ids[IDS[i]].text=texts[i]

class DocApp(App):        
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("docapp\Doc.kv")
        return setText()

if __name__=="__main__":
    DocApp().run()
```

Doc.kv

```
# File: docapp.py
#: import TextInput kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput

GridLayout:
    cols:1
    on_kv_post:
        [self.add_widget(TextInput(id=str(i))) for i in range(2)]
```

I have searched through other questions but couldn't find suitable solution. Please help

Comment: The problem is that your `TextInputs` are not being added by the kv lang, but by the `add_widget()` method of the `GridLayout`. In order for the `ids` to be available, they must be added in the `kv` style (`id: theId`). I have seen this accomplished, but cannot find the post that described it. Essentially, you would call a method that creates a `kv` string, and use `Builder.load_string()` to load it. This can be done inside the `if __name__=="__main__":` block, just before starting the `App`.

Comment: Can you please highlight what changes to be made in the code..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code, is that `id` only works in the kv syntax.
So you need to reference your widgets some other way.
In case you need to do it that way, dynamically adding in kv and accessing in a loop in python, you could try something like the example below.
The text will change after 5 seconds in this case. If you know that the only children of this gridlayout will be the widgets you want to access, you might as well just iterate the children.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

KV = """
#: import TextInput kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput

GridLayout:
    cols:1
    on_kv_post:
        for i in range(2): app.dynamic_widgets.append(TextInput())
        for wid in app.dynamic_widgets: self.add_widget(wid)

"""

class DocApp(App):
    dynamic_widgets = []

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_text, 5)
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def set_text(self, dt):
        texts=['txtip1','txtip2']
        for text, wid in zip(texts, self.dynamic_widgets):
            wid.text = text

if __name__=="__main__":
    DocApp().run()
```

Now if you remove one of the widgets, you probably want to remove it from the list also.

Comment: Thanks it worked...I just wanted to know one thing what is dt argument passed in set_text function?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `TextInput` widgets dynamically in `kv` by creating the `kv` dynamically. Here is a modification of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder


class DocApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # schedule the call to add the texts
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setText)

        # return the root widget from the kvString
        return layoutRoot

    def setText(self, dt):
        texts=['txtip1','txtip2']
        IDS=self.root.ids.keys()
        i = 0
        for id in IDS:
            self.root.ids[id].text=texts[i]
            i += 1


if __name__=="__main__":
    # Create the kv string here
    kvString = '''
GridLayout:
    cols:1
'''
    for i in range(2):
        kvString += '    TextInput:\n' + '        id: ' + str(i) + '\n'

    # Load the kv string
    layoutRoot = Builder.load_string(kvString)

    # and finally, run the App
    DocApp().run()
```

I have eliminated the `setText` class (assuming it was only a holder for the `setText` method), and placed that method in the `App`. The `Clock.schedule_once()` schedules the call to `setText` to happen after the `App` has been created.